# Having trouble with Android 's findViewById

Tags: android

I'm using some pre-generated android code and it isn't working.

Here is the onCreateView function for a Fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabmain, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
```

Here is the xml for this fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.startandselect.agora.tabmain$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

But when I run the problem I get an error on the `textView.setText` line because `textView` is null. `textView` is null because the line before it failed to find the text view. The `findViewById` failed to find it but I do not know why.

I debugged and found that the real textView has an id: 2131492994 and the R.id.section_label has an id of 2131492997.

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project. Make sure you are using the correct layout and the correct id.

Comment: Make sure `R.layout.fragment_tabmain` is the one you want, you might have copied and pasted it so this layout doesn't have your textview and will return null;

Comment: Yup, all I did was clean and rebuild and it worked fine thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karakuri suggested in the comment to clean and rebuild. It was the first thing I attempted and that was all it took, thank you.

**Solution:** Clean and rebuild project.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the following:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.section_label);
```

instead of:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the same android:id  of TextView on another activity layout.

Comment: That shouldn't cause any problem. As long as you don't have duplicate Id's on the same layout file, you will do just fine...